# Error PHPMailer

Tags: php

Hola a todos como están tengo un problema que según la documentación de la librería esta bien mi código

```
require_once '../lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require_once '../autoloadIn.php';
 $cadena = "<p style='display:block;color:red;font:bold;'>Gracias por el CRM<p/>";
  $reporte = ComercialDO::listar_indicardor();
 $mail = New PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
 $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
 $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->Username = 'fortel.luis.cunza@gmail.com';
 $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';
 $mail->setFrom('fortel.luis.cunza@gmail.com','Administrador CRM');
 $mail->addAddress('sgamonal@jamming.pe');
 $mail->Subject = 'Prueba Reporte';
 $mail->msgHTML($cadena.$reporte);
 if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Erro".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}  else {
echo "Mensaje Enviado";
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me muestra este error

> Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
>   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (0)
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>   ErroSMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Segun vi su documentación del error todo esta bien pero no se donde este haciendo mal o tal vez me falte algo Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues el error fue otro tuve que deshabilitar el selinux que fue quien estaba bloqueando la salida claro que esto lo hice en mi servidor donde se encuentra mi aplicacion muchas Gracias a todos

Answer (score 1):

Pueden ser varias causas para este problema

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (0) SMTP
>   connect() failed.

Asegura que exista el SMTP, en ocasiones en el servidor donde tienes tu archivos php no se puede estar leyendo:

```
smtp.gmail.com
```

y que las credenciales son validas

```
 $mail->Username = 'fortel.luis.cunza@gmail.com';
 $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';
```

También verifica que el puerto no este bloqueado:

```
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: Efectivamente. Y por cierto el propio mensaje de error te envia a la pagina del Phpmail en el que te explican los errores mas habituales, entre ellos los que comenta @Elenasys

Answer (score 1):

Quita la linea comentada:

```
$mail = New PHPMailer;

// $mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
```

Y prueba de agregar:

```
require 'class.smtp.php';
```

Si está en desarrollo y corriendo un servidor en local, como Xampp, lo mejor es comentar esa línea. En producción (y todo subido a un servidor comercial), se debe descomentar.

Google es impredecible. Y también entrar en la cuenta de gmail y habilitar la opción de permitir aplicaciones menos seguras:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es

Y por supuesto, si corre Xampp configurar correctamente Mercury, y encenderlo, o no saldrá ningún email. Una guía rápida, en Youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwjNIUuM_iI&t=303s